# Send JSON data format to controller

Tags: c#, json, ajax

I have a table which user can insert multiple rows data and save it in one shot. I made a class named `Observations` :

```
 public class Observations
{
    public string Time { get; set; }
    public string Rate { get; set; }
}
```

I send the parameter using ajax request. The `dataRow` is actually in JSON format and is created after user insert their data.

```
  $.ajax({
        type: 'POST', 
        url: "/Health/SaveObservation",
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data:  JSON.stringify(dataRow),
        dataType: "json",            
    });
```

This is the example of dataRow created:

```
var dataRow = [{"Time":"1","Rate":"12"},{"Time":"2","Rate":"32"}]
```

If the data submitted is one row, it sent successfully to the controller. But if it more than one row, it will show null value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be great if you also post your controller code. But I suppose that SaveObservation action takes a collection of Observations.

Since you need to send an array of data rows which is an array as well you need to change your action parameter to:

```
SaveObservation(List<List<Observations>> data)
```